# How to Manage Equal width of Views

Tags: autolayout, constraints

I have to design a screen with contain 3 views of equal width.& every view has a remove Button to remove particular view. 
when i tap on first remove Button than other two views have to equal with along to base View.

How can i manage constraints for this Situation.
Please anyone tell me how can i manage.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Probably the easiest method is to use a `UIStackView`, with Distribution set to `Fill Equally`.

When you start, the 3 views will each take 1/3 of the width of the Stack View. On button tap, you can use `.removeArrangedSubview()` and the Stack View will automatically re-size the remaining two views to each take up 1/2 of the width.

Comment: Yes, it is Done by stack view. but now i am facing issue that how to manage space between subviews of stackview.